# Ruby - simple way to convert the first letter of string to downcase

Tags: ruby, string, jruby

Is there a simple way to convert the first letter of a string to downcase? `String#capitalize` modifies the entire string. Sure, I can remove the first letter, downcase it and then append it in the beginning. But it seems kinda silly, is there a simpler way?

Note: I'll be dealing with only English words.

Edit: `str[0] = str[0].downcase` doesn't work in JRuby 1.6 :(

Edit 2: In the end I settled on this:

```
word = "ABC"
first_capital_letter = word.match(/^([A-Z])/).to_s
 if(first_capital_letter)
   word = word.sub(first_capital_letter, first_capital_letter.downcase)
   puts word
end
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to downcase the first letter of a string? Are you trying to reverse a previous capitalization?

Comment: Works just fine for me: `jruby --1.9 -e "str = 'ABC'; str[0] = str[0].downcase; p str"` prints `aBC`.

Comment: The telltale sign would be `NoMethodError: undefined method \`downcase' for 65:Fixnum`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
str[0] = str[0].chr.downcase
```

Ruby 1.8.7 returns `integer` instead of `string` for `str[0]`:

```
str = "ABC"
print str[0]        # 65
print str[0..0]     # a
print str[0].chr    # a
```

Comment: Hi! This works for me, Thanks! Does this works in other Ruby versions too?

Comment: It also works on ruby v1.9.2. Not sure about other implementations.

Answer (score 6):

If you really don't want to downcase the first letter and re-append it you could do `str.gsub(/^\w{1}/) { |m| m.downcase }` but that seems silly.

Comment: Silly? Well... that's a matter of opinion I guess. I find it clever:)

Comment: Silly as in people actually may have to think about this for a sec, which they probably wouldn't have to do with `str[0] = str[0].downcase`.

Comment: @Michael: Yep, you're right. Yet it's interesting nonetheless! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "ABC"
=> "ABC"
irb(main):002:0> str[0] = str[0].downcase
=> "a"
irb(main):003:0> str
=> "aBC"
```

Comment: Strange! This works here (http://tryruby.org/), but it doesn't work in JRuby 1.6 :|

Comment: I guess you have a bug report for JRuby team to fill then.

Comment: @huhucat: Are you by any chance running JRuby in 1.8 mode? This code obviously requires Ruby 1.9, so you have to make sure to run JRuby in 1.9 mode.

Comment: @huhucat and @michl: Maybe try `str[0] = str[0].chr.downcase` in JRuby, `str[0]` will return the ASCII value of the first char in Ruby 1.8.

Comment: @Mchl: I don't think this is a bug in JRuby. It works just fine for me. I suspect that the OP is running JRuby in 1.8 mode, where this cannot work for obvious reasons (`String#[]` returns a `Fixnum` but there is no `Fixnum#downcase`).

Comment: @huhucat: The telltale sign would be `NoMethodError: undefined method \`downcase' for 65:Fixnum`.

Comment: I've no experience with JRuby, so I didn't even know you could run it in `1.8` mode. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @Jorg: Yep, I got the `NoMethodError`. @Michael, Yossi: Will `str[0].chr.downcase` work across different Ruby versions?

Comment: @huhucat: Yes, it should work across different Ruby versions.

Answer (score 2):

To be compatible in Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9 mode, you can use:

```
str[0..0] = str[0..0].downcase
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
str.sub(/^\w/) {$&.downcase}
```

**Explanation:** Here, the `sub` substitutes the first matched expression once instead of using `gsub` which substitutes all the matched occurrences. The regular expression `^\w` selects the first alphanumeric character from the entire string and passes it to the block. `$&` captures the matched string and `downcase` converts the string to downcase.

Example:

```
2.3.0 :001 > str = 'Regular expressions in Ruby'
=> "Regular expressions in Ruby" 
2.3.0 :002 > str.sub(/^\w/) {$&.downcase}
=> "regular expressions in Ruby"
```

Comment: A good answer should give some explanation for the code, or at least a context with usage examples. For example, you could explain what this regular expression does and why does it satisfy OP's requiremenets.